# How to open a latest file in a sub directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ls, xargs, unix-head

I have a `logs/` directory which contains many log files. I would like to open the latest log file. My env is Ubuntu 16.

I know the name of the latest file. But the file is in `logs/` dir. In such a case, how do I tell the relative pass via `xargs`?

```
$ ls -t logs/ | head -1
20180615-184233.log

$ ls -t logs/ | head -1 | xargs less
failed
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it by myself. I need `*` for printing the whole relative path.

```
$ ls -t logs/ | head -1
20180615-184233.log

$ ls -t logs/ | head -1 | xargs less
failed 

$ ls -t logs/* | head -1
logs/20180615-184233.log

$ ls -t logs/* | head -1 | xargs less
success
```